# Which sentence is correct? He hit a taxi. or His car hit a taxi

Tags: word-usage

If I want to express that someone had a crash, which sentences below are correct?

1. His car bumped into a taxi.
2. His car hit a taxi.
3. He bumped into a taxi.
4. He hit a taxi.

Comment: He hit a taxi. **can be understood** as he hit a taxi with his car. We don't do sentence correction here. Bear in mind that to bump and to hit are not the same.

Comment: Carol, please do better at explaining why you doubt any of these phrases.  They are all grammatically correct. - what is your doubt?

Comment: The word "bump" is almost gentle in nature, if someone physically bumps into you, they do not hurt you, you are not injured. You can be taken by surprise, you might even feel annoyed but you carry on walking to your destination. When there is a car crash, the cars are damaged, they may be so damaged as to be unrepairable. The drivers will feel the impact and they might be seriously injured too. They may need emergency treatment. This rarely, if ever, happens when two cars only *bump* into each other. A *car crash* is not exactly the same as a *car accident*

Comment: This is a writing assignment. In the paper, I wrote, "His car hit / bumped into a taxi." Yet, my teacher said it was bad. He said that "He hit a taxi" or "He bumped into a taxi" would be better. Also, according to the teacher, "hit" sounds more serious than "bump into." That's why I have this question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

None of them. You need to show that he was driving the car when the accident occurred:

He was driving his car when it bumped into a taxi.

He was driving his car when it hit a taxi.

He was driving his car and it bumped into a taxi.

He was driving his car when it hit a taxi.

He was driving his car and it hit a taxi.

Comment: I don't agree at all.

Comment: Not true. In colloquial speech _He hit a taxi_ would be understood to mean that the vehicle he was driving hit one.

Comment: For those who disagree, the question is "If I want to express that someone had a crash," anything less than the examples does not do the job. **Absent other context,** and there is none, it does not take much imagination to see as 1., 2, 3, and 4 as all not involving the driver in question.  "He was driving" must inform the sentence.